# Xcode 5.1 : "iOS simulator failed to install application"

Tags: ios-simulator, warnings, xcode5.1

I'm getting warning while running an application on simulator using **Xcode 5.1**. The warning states "**iOS simulator failed to install application**". This occurs more frequently while **switching between different simulator** (OS). What might be reason and possible solution?

[image]